# Need to switch from SQLite3 to MySQL, and want to deploy with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are currently using `SQLite3` as our database and want to switch it to `MySQL` before we send our Rails app live via Passenger and Nginx to our Linode Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid box.

we set up the msql server on our linode ubuntu 10.04 box
and set a password for the root user. how do we configure `database.yml` ? what are the steps to set up this `MySQL` database? We have the `mysql2` gem installed and in our Gemfile.

What does `database.yml` need to look like in order to deploy with `MySQL` ?

Does the database need any specific name as in `database name`?

Do we go about running `rake db:create` on our machine or run it on our Ubuntu box?

current `database.yml`

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3
# 
# Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
# gem 'sqlite3'
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 2000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 2000

production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: production
pool: 5
username: root
password: "mysql password"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a simple connection test? If not, here is a script to test the connection to your db.

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

# getting required gems  
require 'rubygems'  
require 'mysql'  

## ----- test the connection -----  
# http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/frames  
# real_connect(host=nil, user=nil, passwd=nil, db=nil, port=nil, sock=nil, flag=nil)
mysql = Mysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db_name', 3006, '', '')  

## ----- if connected, will list databases -----  
puts mysql.list_dbs().to_s
```

In case the 'mysql' did not install properly, you will have to custom configure the install properties. On my Mac (different that you linux machine), I referenced [this blog post](http://geryit.com/blog/installing-mysql-with-rails-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) to get something like this,

`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with mysqlconfig=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

**UPDATE** - Had to reinstall mysql gem for a different ruby version, and removing the architecture notation allowed me to install the gem.

`sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 1):

On your production server, go to your app's root directory and type `nano config/database.yml` and paste this code in.  Change the names.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: something_production
  username: somethingotherthanroot
  password: passwordnostring
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Now, either create the database on your own, on the server, or you can run `rake RAILS_ENV=production db:create:all`hell i've never tried but i'm sure you can do `rake db:create:production` too.

once done, just do `rake RAILS_ENV=production db:migrate`

Comment: this answer makes so much sense, one of the best we've seen so far. but for some reason when we run these commands our ssh root@ipv6 cant recgonzie our hostname. we are burnt on configuring this hostname issue and as of five minutes ago are looking to deploy with heroku. we need to get this thing out and dont have time to absord linode, passenger, and nginx's massive learning curve. especially when it comes to database configuration in two separate locations, on the ubuntu 10.04 lucid box and in our own local app directory.

Comment: http://articles.slicehost.com/ubuntu-10 follow along. I've used this a few times and never came across that. plus logging in as root is a bad idea mate. ubuntu is bad, but i am biased cause i hate it. Ok it ain't bad... i just prefer another distro named after a penguin.

Comment: we dumped linode, ubuntu, passenger and nginx. jumped over to heroku. seamless, quick, and garbage free

Comment: shame. Why would you leave it to the last moment?  You should have been planning this for weeks, especially if it's your first app, as it sounds.  however live and learn. later.

Comment: admittance of my lack of planning. we thought deployment would be quick and easy especially with passenger as it was rails' own "recommendation" we allotted around four to five hours for deployment and used all of that and more just trying to configure everything. four other devs recommended heroku and we switched just before the point where i was going to smash my macbook. thanks for sticking with us, best for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your database.yml is fine, except for the fact that you should have your production name database named like this: projectname_production

Answering your question of how to create the database once on the server, ssh into your application server and do a rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production

This will create the production database on the server. Same thing with your migration. It should be rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production. This will start the migration for your production database.

Comment: to be honest we just dumped our linode passenger ngix stack and jumped into heroku. were trying to deploy cleanly and dont have time for the massive learning curve necessary with the aforementioned implementation.